# python algorithm, find duplicates in list

Tags: python, algorithm

I need to find all unique values in python list, and if there was a duplicate write how many of them, example:

```
['apple','cherry','coffee','apple','coffee','coffee']
```

and the output should be:

```
apple 2
cherry 1
coffee 3
```

Comment: Dup: [How can I count the occurrences of a list item in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a homework... Here's a straight forward approach:

```
lst = ['apple','cherry','coffee','apple','coffee','coffee']

res = {}
for obj in lst:
    if obj not in res:
        res[obj] = 0
    res[obj] += 1

print res
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(['apple','cherry','coffee','apple','coffee','coffee'])
Counter({'coffee': 3, 'apple': 2, 'cherry': 1})
>>> for k,v in _.items():
...   print k,v
... 
cherry 1
coffee 3
apple 2
```